# Node.js npm can't get past proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am struggling to get `npm install` to work properly behind a corporate proxy here. I configured the proxy with the `config set` command, but unfortunately it always throws this error:

```
37 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:26:54
38 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
39 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
40 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
41 info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:27:25
42 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
43 info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:27:25
44 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
45 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
46 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
47 info attempt registry request try #3 at 09:28:46
48 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
49 info attempt registry request try #3 at 09:28:46
50 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
51 verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
51 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
51 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
51 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
52 verbose cwd U:\
53 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
54 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
55 error node v4.4.3
56 error npm  v2.15.1
57 error code ETIMEDOUT
58 error errno ETIMEDOUT
59 error syscall connect
60 error network connect ETIMEDOUT 10.254.49.103:80
```

My config looks like this:

```
proxy http://proxyadress.org:8080/
https-proxy https://proxyadress.org:8080/
```